# How do I render a partial to a string from within a filter attached to a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, filter

I have some code I need to use in multiple controllers in a rails 1.0 application (I can't, for strange reasons upgrade to a newer rails).  I've extracted the relevant code into a filer object, and I'm using the around_filter construct to execute it.

Before the extract, I was using the method render_to_string() to get the contents of a rendered partial into a string.  However, this method is protected, so I am unable to access it from within my Filter object.  As a workaround, I tried adding this to my ApplicationController:

```
def render_to_string(*a)
  super(*a)
end
```

this seems to have remedied the protection level issue, but now I get the error:

```
Can only render or redirect once per action
```

When no such error occurred before the extraction.  Why?  Is there a different approach I should take here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell , an action will call render prior to executing any filters.  Since render_to_string works by running render, saving the result to a string and essentially undoing the render, the "Can only render or redirect once per action" comes up because the temporary call to render comes after the "real" call to render.

I fixed this, by simply calling my after method at the end of my action rather than using after_filter or around_filter.

I also ended up moving my filters into a Mix-in, to more elegantly avoid the protection level issue.